# How can i join 1 id fields from a table to 2 different table colums

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a school menagement program in which i want to connect multiple tables to the Students table, i want to use the Cities ID field for both of the Stundents BirthPlace and their actual Address in the table but i can't figure it out how to do it.

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.Name, Students.Birthday, Students.MothersName, Classes.ClassName, Cities.Name, Cities.Name,
PostalCode.PostalCode, Street.StreetName, Students.Number

FROM Students

INNER JOIN Classes ON Students.ClassID = Classes.ClassID
INNER JOIN Cities ON Students.BirthPlaceID = Cities.CityID
INNER JOIN Cities ON Students.CityID = Cities.CityID
INNER JOIN PostalCode ON Students.PostalCodeID = PostalCode.PostalCodeID
INNER JOIN Utca ON Students.StreetID = Streets.StreetID
```

i've tried this way but it only results in error.

Comment: need to use different aliases for BirthPlaceCity and AddressCity

Comment: When you post in any online forum for help with code because you received an error you should ALWAYS include the error message. Fortunately it was easy to spot this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create an alias for the table in your select and then you can access the same table with 2 different identifies. I did the same (created alias) for the values in your select statement to identify which city is which.

```
SELECT Students.StudentID, Students.Name, Students.Birthday, Students.MothersName, Classes.ClassName, StudentBirthCities.Name as StudentBirthCityName, StudentCity.Name as StudentCityName,
PostalCode.PostalCode, Street.StreetName, Students.Number

FROM Students

INNER JOIN Classes ON Students.ClassID = Classes.ClassID
INNER JOIN Cities StudentBirthCities ON Students.BirthPlaceID = StudentBirthCities.CityID
INNER JOIN Cities StudentCity ON Students.CityID = StudentCity.CityID
INNER JOIN PostalCode ON Students.PostalCodeID = PostalCode.PostalCodeID
INNER JOIN Utca ON Students.StreetID = Streets.StreetID
```

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpfull, now it runs correctly